# Copying a Parent Directory into a Subdirectory Without an Infinite Loop

Tags: shell, files, file-copy

For application specific reasons, I need to copy an entire parent directory into a subdirectory. E.g.,

`cp -r ../ tmp/`

The problem with this is that it gets stuck in an infinite loop, recursively copying the contents of tmp/ over and over again.

There are a number of ways around this, like tarring the directory and unpacking it in tmp, but I'm wondering if there are any particularly elegant/unixy solutions.

(note: I'm using Apple OS/X).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you start from the parent directory, you can do this with `find` and GNU `cp`. Assuming the directory you're in currently (the one containing `tmp`) is called `folder`, and that `tmp` is empty, you'd run

```
cd ..
find . -path ./folder/tmp -prune -o -type f -exec cp --parents -t folder/tmp {} +
```

This asks find to list everything under `.` (which is your old `..`), exclude it if it matches `./folder/tmp`, and otherwise if it's a file pass it to `cp` with the `--parents` option (which tells `cp` to reconstruct the source hierarchy).

If `tmp` already has files which also need to be copied, the following variant is slightly less Unix-y (since it uses [`moreutils`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)' `sponge`) but avoids skipping the contents of `tmp`:

```
cd ..
find . -type f -print0 | sponge | xargs -0 cp --parents -t folder/tmp
```

You could avoid the use of `sponge` by saving the list of files to copy in a file somewhere else (but then things get rather less elegant):

```
cd ..
find . -type f -print0 > /tmp/filelist
xargs -0 cp --parents -t folder/tmp < /tmp/filelist
rm /tmp/filelist
```

You can avoid the requirement on GNU `cp` by using `cpio` instead:

```
cd ..
find . -type f -print0 > /tmp/filelist
cpio -pmd0 folder/tmp < /tmp/filelist
rm /tmp/filelist
```

or

```
cd ..
find . -type f -print0 | sponge | cpio -pmd0 folder/tmp
```

If `tmp` is empty you can also avoid the requirement on `moreutils`:

```
cd ..
find . -path ./folder/tmp -prune -o -type f -print0 | cpio -pmd0 folder/tmp
```

Comment: Oh yes, I assumed `tmp` was empty but that may well be wrong!

Comment: When I try this I get `cp: illegal option -- -`. I'm actually 3 levels up in the hierarchy. The command looks like this: `find . -path ./docker/app/tmp/ -prune -o -type f -exec cp --parents -t docker/app/tmp/ {} +`

Comment: Does it work if you add `-- ` before `{}`? As in `cp --parents -t docker/app/tmp -- {} +`...

Comment: No -- I get the same error.

Comment: Hmm... What does `cp --version` say? Does the last `cpio` variant work?

Comment: `cp --version` gives me the usage screen for cp. I should have mentioned I'm actually doing this on OSX, so it's the BSD cp that ships with the OS. I guess this is one of the cases where the mac utils are annoyingly different than their unix/linux counterparts in subtle ways. The problem is I'm writing  this as a util for the team, and most of them develop on macs. It's a tool for building containers, so once I get them in the containers I have control, but before that I can't enforce a specific version of cp or get sponge installed on the system.

Comment: That's why I mentioned the requirement on GNU `cp`. I've added a variant without GNU `cp` and `moreutils`, it works on Mac OS X (but it doesn't copy `tmp` so it's appropriate only if `tmp` is empty).

Answer (score 0):

For interactive use, I have a hack for the analogous case with mv:

```
cd ..
mv * tmp

mv: cannot move ‘tmp’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘tmp/tmp’
```

Ignore the error, everything else got moved :-P.  Doesn't work quite the same with cp, it creates an empty tmp/tmp, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

With `pax`, to copy `.` into `subdir/tmp`, skipping `subdir/tmp`:

```
mkdir -p subdir/tmp &&
  pax -rws'|^\./subdir/tmp/.*||' . subdir/tmp
```

Alternatively, you could do something like:

```
mkdir -p subdir/tmp/subdir &&
  ln -s tmp subdir/tmp/subdir/tmp &&
  cp -a . subdir/tmp
```

`subdir/tmp/subdir/tmp` is then a symlink to itself, to `cp` won't be able to create anything under it. You can replace it with an empty directory afterwards if you want.