# What should 'cp -r srcpath/.. dstpath' do?

Tags: cp

Consider the following:

```
/tmp$ mkdir -p src/{a,b} dst/dstsub; touch src/{a,b}/hello
/tmp$ tree src/ dst/
src/
├── a
│   └── hello
└── b
    └── hello
dst/
└── dstsub
```

Now run

```
/tmp$ cp -r src/a/.. dst/dstsub/
```

With GNU cp, this results in the contents of `src` == `src/a/..` being copied in `dst/dstsub`, like so:

```
/tmp$ tree dst/
dst/
└── dstsub
    ├── a
    │   └── hello
    └── b
        └── hello
```

However, repeating the exercise with Busybox results in a different destination structure:

```
/tmp$ rm -r dst/; mkdir -p dst/dstsub
/tmp$ busybox cp -r src/a/.. dst/dstsub/
/tmp$ tree dst/
dst/
├── a
│   └── hello
├── b
│   └── hello
└── dstsub
```

Here, the contents of the source directory `src` == `src/a/..` were copied *alongside* the destination directory `dst/dstsub/`, not *in* it.

Trying to read the standard text:

> ```
>  cp -R [-H|-L|-P] [-fip] source_file... target
> ```
>
> [...] The cp utility shall copy each file in the file hierarchy rooted in each *source_file* to a destination path named as follows:
>
> If *target* exists and names an existing directory, the name of the corresponding destination path for each file in the file hierarchy shall be the concatenation of *target*, a single *<slash>* character if *target* did not end in a *<slash>*, and the pathname of the file relative to the directory containing *source_file*.

*Target* is `dst/dstsub/`, it's an existing directory and ends in a slash. *Source_file* is `src/a/..`, so the directory containing it is `src/a/` and the pathnames relative to the directory containing it are `../a`, `../b` etc., which would result in the destination paths `dst/dstsub/../a`, `dst/dstsub/../b` etc., matching Busybox's behaviour.

However, if we first canonicalize the source path to remove `..`, it would be `src/` (or rather `src/.`, since the behaviour is that `src` itself is not copied, as would happen with `cp -r src dst` which would create `dst/src`). This would result in destination paths like `dst/dstsub/./a` etc., which seems to match what GNU cp does. (I don't know if it does exactly that, but this seems a plausible explanation.)

The only mention of `..` (*dot-dot*) being special I can see in the standard text is this:

> 2. If *source_file* is of type directory, the following steps shall be taken:
>
> b. If *source_file* was not specified as an operand and *source_file* is *dot* or *dot-dot*, cp shall do nothing more with *source_file* and go on to any remaining files.

And this doesn't apply since the path containing `..` was explicitly given as a command-line operand. Also the operand wasn't exactly `..` in case it matters, but I get the same results with both GNU and Busybox with just `..` as the source directory:

```
/tmp$ cd src/a/
/tmp/src/a$ cp -r .. /tmp/dst/dstsub/
```

---

Is the canonicalization of `..` described above (or equivalent behaviour) allowed by the standard? Should it be done? Should it *not* be done? Or was there something else I missed about the behaviour of GNU cp or the interpretation of the standard text?

Comment: Obviously, that's not what I'd usually do, and "don't do that" would in most cases be a valid answer. This came up when I tried to figure out what the command in [Why does 'cp -r ../* .' work but not 'cp -r .. .'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/595250/170373) should do.

Comment: IMO the `-v` option reveals something interesting. GNU `cp` says `'src/a/../a' -> 'dst/dstsub/a'`, while `busybox cp` says `'src/a/../a' -> 'dst/dstsub/../a'`. And the [source](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/947c553ff92b6edbc6f5a9f43172ebf7e58a1d21/src/cp.c#L699) says that removing trailing dot-dot(s) from _source\_file_ before concatenating to _target_ is intended, but it doesn't say why.

Comment: Adding to the mix, `cp` on FreeBSD (12.1), whose manual says it's expected to be POSIX.2 compatible, behaves as GNU `cp` (i.e. copies into `dstsub`); its verbose output is slightly different, though: `src/a/../a -> dst/dstsub/./a`.